# How to write any member of a sigma algebra as a subset of a countable union of members of the generating algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, outer-measure

I’m currently working my way through Real Analysis by Folland and, in his proof of theorem 1.14 he does something I don’t quite understand:

Take some algebra $\mathcal{A}$ on some set $X$ which generates some $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{M}$. If we have $E \in \mathcal{M}$ then we write $E \subset A$, where $A := \cup_{1}^{\infty} A_j$ for some $A_j \in \mathcal{A}$. Now, I believe this is possible because $X \in \mathcal{A}$ and $E \subset X$. However, what I don’t understand is that he then goes on to say that, given some $\epsilon > 0$ we can choose the $A_j$’s in such a way that $\mu(A) \leq \mu(E) + \epsilon$ for a measure $\mu$ on $(X, \mathcal{M})$. How can we make such a choice?

Comment: What is stated in your title is trivial, as you say.  So the point is the existence of $A_j \supseteq E$ with $\mu(A_j) \leq \mu(E) + \epsilon$.  For this use the definition of "$\sigma$-algebra generated by".

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I’m not seeing how the definition of “$\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}$” leads to the selection of such $A_j$. The definition I have is that this is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{A}$. I don’t really see the link, sorry